# Springboot @ConfigurationProperties with prefix, how to retrieve a nested property without creating an intermediate Object attribut?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

Followed the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) and it works fine.
But I can't find if there is a way to retrieved a nested properties without creating a middle Object attribut.

**application.properties :**

```
mail.host=localhost
mail.port=25
mail.smtp.auth=false
mail.smtp.starttls-enable=false
mail.middle.attr=test
```

**Configuration service :**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mail")
@Component
public class MyConfService {
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public static class Smtp {

        private boolean auth;
        private boolean starttlsEnable;

        // ... Getters & Setters

    }

    // ... Getters & Setters
}
```

This works perfectly.

But how can I retrieve `mail.middle.attr` directly without having to create a `middle` Object attribut with a `attr` attribut ?
And without having to go back to ugly @Value ;)

Comment: Plain old `@Value`s!

Comment: Hehe yeah I know, but I'd lose the benefit of the prefix,

Comment: I think for that you must create object. Either nested class or standalone.